# Where controllers should be placed in Meteor App?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm creating a Meteor app using iron:router. According to documentation I can create controllers.

```
BaseController = RouteController.extend({
    layoutTemplate: 'mainLayout'
});
```

Configuration file for routing is placed right now in /lib folder. Should I also placed controllers inside same folder or better inside client?

As far as I know, collection initialization and methods for that collection should be placed inside lib folder.

Can someone explain me how proper meteor app structure should look like? I've read best practices from Meteor documentation, but there are only general tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place Controllers inside the `/lib/` folder. This makes it available to the client as well as the server.

Essentially, you can make your own file structure in Meteor. Just follow some kind of rules and even if things get out of hand, it's not hard to move/rename files. I haven't found anyone recommending any "hard" rules.

In my case, I put all router files inside `/lib/router/` and Controllers would be located in `/lib/router/controllers/`. So a `HomeController` would be placed in `/lib/router/controllers/home.js` for example.

Comment: Ok, but why controllers should be available for client also? I always thought that controllers should be placed on server side. Does it not make them easy, vulnerable to access by users?

Comment: @Forin Controllers share same responsibility and functionality as routes. [Route controllers are used mostly for inheritance and organization](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#route-controllers). In essence, controllers are still very similar to routes themselves - which you place in your `/lib/` folder, correct? There's really nothing to "hide" in a controller - you shouldn't give a controller/route that big of a responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure there is a ’best practice’ for this yet. Personally I like to segregate my code by its target. So I have a

`/client
/server
/lib
/public`

setup. Stuff that only should run on the server (e.g. your DAL) goes in the sever folder and is then broken into sub-folders by its function. Stuff that runs client and server side (e.g. routers) go in the lib folder (the benefit being that Meteor looks for this folder and loads that before the client/server folders). Static files such as CSS go in the public folder. In my example above, controllers are a sub-folder of the lib folder.

This is, of course, personal preference but works well for my muscle memory. Would be interest to see how others structure their projects.

Comment: DAL? Can you explain this shortcut? I think is better to put css files inside client's subfolder i.e. stylesheets

Comment: Sorry, DAL = Data Access Layer (so any DB access you may have to Mongo or whatever Db technology you may be using). You'll want to isolate that from the client to stop those pesky customers messing ;)

Comment: You mean that collections should be placed inside server folder?